# How to align a SwiftUI navigationBarTitle to be centered?

Tags: swiftui, xcode11, ios13

How does one centre a navigation bar title in SwiftUI?

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        .navigationBarTitle("Todo Lists")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`.navigationBarTitle` allows for three display modes - `.large`, `.inline`, and `.automatic`.

From the documentation:

> ```swift
> case automatic
> ```
>
> > Inherit the display mode from the previous navigation item.
>
> ```swift
> case inline
> ```
>
> > Display the title within the standard bounds of the navigation bar.
>
> ```swift
> case large
> ```
>
> > Display a large title within an expanded navigation bar.

So it depends what you mean when you say "how does one centre a navigation bar title in SwiftUI?" You cannot center a navigation bar title that has a display mode of `.large`. You also cannot left-align or right-align a navigation bar title that has a display mode of `.inline`. If you want a navigation bar title that is centered, then your only option is to use `.inline`.

```swift
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        CustomView()
            .navigationBarTitle("Todo Lists", displayMode: .inline)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22):

Also, an awesome approach was shown [here](https://sarunw.com/posts/custom-navigation-bar-title-view-in-swiftui/).

It's perfect when you need to customize navbar. Keyword `.principal` is for positioning

```
NavigationView {
    Text("Hello, SwiftUI!")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "sun.min.fill")
                    Text("Title").font(.headline)
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: The best answer, this works like a charm! thanks

Comment: Great answer here, although I missed off the ToobarItem(placement: ...... as I was getting errors. I got this approach to work with the HStack{...} just right within the .toolbar {...}  I got my text lined up just where I wanted it!

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the text format in title. But here is a work around, it will work as requested (without large gap):

```
HStack{
    Text("Todo Lists")
}
.multilineTextAlignment(.center)
.font(.largeTitle)
.padding(.bottom, -15.0)
NavigationView{
    List{
        ForEach(instrNewOld) { instrIdx in
            SourceCodeView(cat: instrIdx)
        }
    }
    .navigationBarTitle(Text("no text"), displayMode: .automatic)
    .navigationBarHidden(true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an option. Using 'navigationBarHidden(true)' 
Only downside is that it creates a large gap between the image and the tableview.

```
struct ContentView: View{
var body: some View {
            VStack
            {
                CircleImageView()
                HeadLineView()
                NavigationView
                {
                        List
                        {
                            Text("Line 1")
                            Text("Line 2")
                        }
                        .navigationBarHidden(true)
                }
            }
        }
    }

struct HeadLineView : View
{
    var body: some View{
        Text("Headline").bold().font(Font(UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30.0)))
    }
}
```